# Running / controlling an emulator on remote server

Tags: android, mobile, appium

I use couple of Android apps on daily bases, and it's very time consuming.
I want to somehow automatize the process.

The idea is to install some sort of emulator on the server, and program that emulator through some programming language to run the apps on the server when its needed.

I'm a web developer, I work with `PHP`, `nodejs`, `python`,
not really familiar with mobile space.

Is there any solution out there to do what I want?
I search around and found [Appium](http://appium.io/) but I'm not sure if it would do what I want.

Please note these apps don't have a public 'api' for me to use.

Also I only have remote access to server via 'ssh terminal', so solutions with 'GUI' dependency wont work for me.

Comment: You say that they don't have a **public** API, but do they maybe have a private one that some smart cookie has reverse-engineered? Example: https://github.com/Jamonek/Robinhood

Comment: @Dylan its easy to find the api using tools like fiddler, but they use encryption to send & receive data and its almost impossible to find encryption method without access to source code

Answer (score 3):

You can use some emulator, like Bluestacks and then run a script to run apps and then use macro tool to emulate clicks in the games or apps

check this link for the macro tool in bluestacks : https://www.bluestacks.com/blog/bluestacks-exclusives/combo-key-bluestacks-record-replay-action-single-key-en.html

Or you can write a script which uses adb commands to run and control the app.

For example. 
to run apps. `adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings` 
this command will open the settings app in the emulator.

to send touch events you can use : `adb shell input touch <x> <Y>`

```
adb shell input keyevent <keycode> to send keycodes
```

Comment: thanx , bluestacks seems very nice however it seems to need a GUI to run and im working with a remote server via ssh terminal ... im looking for a solution that can be activated/controlled  via a programing code not a graphical interface

Comment: adb seems more suitable for what i want but i would prefer something other than shell script ... preferably nodejs/js bcuz of flexibility it brings like possibility of working with http requests  , database , ....

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to automate native Android apps.

Short answer: Appium will be good solution for you.

On your remote server you will need:

- [Android SDK and Simulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/)
- Python 2.7 installed
- Appium server/node (install using [node.js npm](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/?lang=en) )

With everything installed you will be able to start Appium Nodes on your server and run Appium scripts against them.

I suggest using CI server of choise for automating this process. It should make  starting your test trough ssh terminal easier / 100% automated.

I never used Selenium/Appium in python, so I can't really help you with Appium tests code examples, but I'm sure there are a lot of basic tutorials for python.

Comment: thanx , im  going to use nodejs not python (if possible) ,  im very new to this space .... can we keep the app open on the emulator and use it over a period of time or  it would open the app every time we need to use it ?

Comment: I'm quite sure you can configure Appium to use already running app, but I think it would be better for your script stability to do a fresh start of your app when you need to do something. As for python, it's not for you. Appium node needs it for some reason (or at least appium-doctor thinks it does).

Answer (score 1):

You must install AppiumServer and android sdk/simulator in the remote server. I am going to show how it can be done in java. Hope you can convert it into javascript code.

Check the ip Address of your remote server using **ipconfig**

Start your appium server in the remote server

```
>appium -a "ip address of remote server" -p 4732 --session-override
```

Start the emulator in the remote server.

Define and initialize **DesiredCapabilities** and **AppiumDriver** in your code like following.

```
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
DesiredCapabilities caps= new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "android device");
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 300);
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "enter your appPackage");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "enter your appActivity");

driver= new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("remote server ip address" + ":4732/wd/hub"), caps);
```

> Make sure both device are in the same network. you must get response while pinging to the remote server ip address

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a headless android emulator with this command, it works without needing to be logged into desktop on the remote or if you use wayland.

`emulator $name_of_avd -no-window`

If you are logged into an X session, this way it renders on the gpu it's a little bit faster.

`DISPLAY=:0 emulator $name_of_avd -gpu host -no-window`

Then forward the adb port onto the network with:

```
adb forward tcp:1234 tcp:5555
adb tcpip 5555
ssh -Nfg -L 1234:localhost:5555 localhost
```

Add the 1234 tcp port to your firewall.

On your local machine, connect to the emulator's adb instance:

`adb connect <LAN IP>:1234`

Then use `scrcpy` or Android Studio's built-in screen mirroring to access the device's screen.